# Distribute percentage equally across multiple elements of xml tags

Tags: c#

I am working on modifying an XML file with various percentage values. There are multiple elements across a single XML file. I have percentage for one particular element and I need to distribute the remaining percentage to remaining elements. Below is my sample XML file stored in the server.

```or-tag-here
<exam>
    <name>Maths</name>
    <percentage>100</percentage>
</exam>
<exam>
    <name>Physics</name>
    <percentage>70</percentage>
</exam>
<exam>
    <name>Chemistry</name>
    <percentage>70</percentage>
</exam>
```

I have the percentage value of one particular subject. For example I have the percentage value of maths and I updated the percentage value of maths with the below code by hardcoding it.

```
foreach (XElement xmltag1 in xmltag.Descendants(subsection))
{
    if (xmltag1.Element("name").Value.Equals("Maths")) 
    {   
        xmltag1.Element("percentage").Value = "75";
    }
}
```

Now I need to update the percentage values of remaining subjects that is for physics and chemistry with whole numbers and not with decimals. So I am using the below logic for it.

```
int totalsections = subclasscount;
// subclass count is a method which would return the total number of subclasses inside a particular xml tag. I have that method available with me
int remainingallocatedpercentage = 25 / totalsections;
foreach (XElement xmltag1 in xmltag.Descendants(subsection))
{
    if ((remainingallocatedpercentage % 1) == 0)
    {
        if (!xmltag1.Element("name").Value.Equals("Maths"))
        {                                                       
             xmltag1.Element("percentage").Value = remainingallocatedpercentage;
        }
    }
    else
    {
    }         
}
```

I am not very sure on how to handle the else path. So I need the logic to implement it. I would like to let you know that I do not know what other subject values are available (Like physics, chemistry there are multiple subjects which are dynamic and not static) so i need to distribute the remaining percentage equally among all the subjects.

Comment: The question is, what do you want to do in the else clause?

Comment: Marco sorry for the confusion I have edited my question now and now you should be able to figure out what i exactly need.

Comment: In the else clause i want to allocate the percentage equally among the remaining subjects with whole numbers. for maths i have 75 allocated so i want to allocate 22 for physics and 23 for chemistry.

Answer (score 0):

First of all that piece of code would not work since `int remainingallocatedpercentage = 25 / totalsections;` will always get a whole number value. Instead you can do:

```
var remainingallocatedpercentage = 25 / (float)totalsections;
```

After applying this, now you have a chance to fall to the `else` condition of your code.

Then your actual question begins. But there must be a strategy to handle that case. In your `else` case, you can go with the following approaches:

1. Just setting the floor value of the floating numbers to the other class values. Which is pretty straightforward:

   ```
   xmltag1.Element("percentage").Value = remainingallocatedpercentage;
   ```
2. Setting floor value to all of them except the last one, and set remaining part to the last one. Which is a little tedious:

   ```
   if(!xmltag1.Element("name").Value.Equals(xmltag.Descendants(subsection).LastOrDefault().Element("name").Value))
   {
       xmltag1.Element("percentage").Value = remainingallocatedpercentage;
   }
   else
   {
       xmltag1.Element("percentage").Value = remainingallocatedpercentage + 1;
   }
   ```

I don't know which approach suits you, but since you have that whole number constraint, you don't have much chance than these.